# Access GitHub within GitLab over deployed key from GitHub

Tags: github, continuous-integration, gitlab, ssh-keys

I have one question since a while. The question is, is it possible to access GitHub within Gitlab over an deployed key(ssh key). Also an other solution could be possible, my main goal is, if an push is done into Github, Gitlab will register this and executes automation. What I try to prevent is, that GitLab has access to all repos within GitHub. GitHub OAuth and token doesn't work because it gives access to all my repos within Github.

Best Regards

Comment: also one possibility is to use a machine user, but this is the last solution I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the Repository Mirroring option in Gitlab. This allows you to mirror a repository from Github, Bitbucket, etc to Gitlab, or from Gitlab to another service.

To pull into Gitlab, first create a new project in Gitlab then go to Settings, Repository, Mirroring Repositories and set it up however you require. The full details are available in their documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html#pulling-from-a-remote-repository

Note that for now, this is a paid feature so you must have `starter`/`core` or above.

Comment: Unfortunately the "Pull" function within "Mirror direction" is not available for my self hosted GitLab instance.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer to reference that. You can still mirror to gitlab without the paid version, but a little more work is required. First, you could theoretically host a second, paid gitlab instance that just 1 or 2 people access and pull from github to there, then push from paid gitlab to main gitlab. The second option requires more work, but you could create an app that acts as a middleman: by receiving webhooks from github, you can clone/pull the changed repos, then push them to gitlab.

Comment: Thank you for that but currently I am trying to prevent to invest money and the toolchain might be easy but not as easy as I want. Much thanks for your answer